# Edit and Delete button disabling is not working in IE9 but it works in IE 11

Tags: javascript

Edit and Delete button disabling is not working in IE9 but it works in IE 11
i have applied class disable button to Edit and Delete buttton.. It works in all browser but it doesnt work in IE9...

```
.disablebutton {
cursor: default;
pointer-events: none;
color:gray !important;
```

}

Comment: IE<11 don't have support for `pointer-events`. You could use `disabled` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't support css pointer-events property

[List of browsers that do have support of pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)

You can use `disabled` attribute and then use it in selector for styling

```
<button disabled>I'm disabled</button>
```

CSS

```
button[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
    color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pointer-events` does not work in IE9. Check this http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events.

Try checking for the class at the JavaScript end and then disable the functionality.

I use [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) to check Browser compatibility all the times.